# Does wix contain : 'This website is created using Wix' in the website

Tags: html

I just started using Wix for creating a website.
Can anyone please tell me - when I publish my website, would this be written at the top and bottom of the page?

```
'This website is created using Wix'
```

I know, it should not but was just anxious.

Comment: Wrong tag - WiX = Windows Installer XML.

Comment: What's the harm in trying it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming, but an application feature.

Answer (score 0):

Wix does not contain such statement. But, if you are using the free web site, your site url will be your-site-name.wix.com.
If you are using your own domain, wix will not be mentioned